# Unable to write to bot state property after accessor has been created

Tags: botframework

Perhaps a misunderstanding on my behalf, but in botframework SDKv4, once I create a property accessor for a set of variables I wish to capture in an adaptive dialog, I can no longer write to them directly from input actions.

e.g. prior to initializing a property I can have an input action such as

```cs
new TextInput()
{
    Prompt = new ActivityTemplate("${RequestPhoneNumber()}"),
    Property = "user.profile.mobilenumber",
}
```

Then later I can refer to that property in an adaptive expression, or by checking the dialog context

```cs
var phone = dc.State["user.profile.mobilenumber"];
```

and I'll find the text the user entered inside that property, as expected.

However, if I go and create a data class like:

```cs
public class Person
{
  public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

then create it in my dialog

```cs
var personAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<Person>("profile");
```

If I read the mobilephone property later I'll find the property null after the TextInput action has completed

```cs
Person profile = await personAccessor.GetAsync(dc.Context, () => new Profile());
Console.WriteLine(profile.MobileNumber);
```

The output on the console is null, and I can't quite work out what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding.

Comment: I have noticed that if the property is a string instead of a class, the TextInput action is able to write to the required variable. 

Comment: is your issue resolved?